# AWS Powershell Module Set-AWSCredentials

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

We use several Powershell scripts that rely on having access to our AWS account.  We use `Set-AWSCredentials` to set the access and secret keys.  This has worked fairly well, except lately the credentials have gone missing just over the course of a day.  Previously the credentials would stay put for months, but we now have to run `Set-AWSCredentials` every day.

Is anyone else seeing the same thing?  What can I do to debug what's happening?

Comment: Have you recently edited your powershell profile?  It may no longer be setting your AWS default settings. Try running `Initialize-AWSDefaults` and see if it still has your past credentials.

Comment: We have not recently edited this user's powershell profile.  I ran `Initialize-AWSDefaults`, and it says they've been set now.  I guess we'll see if that does anything.

Comment: Getting the same issue again, this is after I've run `Initialize-AWSDefaults`.

Answer (score -1):

after you set credentials and default region(if you wish)
run 
Initialize-AWSDefaults